# IntelliJ New UI - global breadcrumb navigation

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide

I have enabled the new app UI and I would like to modify global breadcrumb navigation:

[image]

Here I would like to set "start point". As if the first six items are hidden and the navigation starts at "api", because first six items are irrelevant:

[image]

I tried lot's of things, but without success.
Anyone have any ideas on how to change this?

Thanks :)

I've tried changes in settings, Google it, and also tried ChatGPT, but I honestly don't know what I am looking for.

Comment: As far as I know this **Navigation Bar** displays path starting at/relative to the Module / Content Root.